# Как запустить приложение с compose.yaml, Dockerfile, Spring Boot

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

Всем привет! Подскажите, плиз, как запустить проект? Есть compose.yaml, в котором только postgres, Dockerfile c описанием образа для создания приложения и Spring Boot.  Использовать docker-compose up чтобы запустить контейнер с postgres, потом docker build, docker run чтобы запустить контейнер с приложением? И приложением должно запуститься? Метод main в классе с SpringBootApplication не нужно запускать?